# Having problems getting Python 2.6 to link with custom module built in

Tags: c++, python, linux, python-2.6

I have been trying to get Python 2.6 to build on Linux with a custom module for the past week and have been having a lot of problems. My latest one seems to be another linker issues when Python tries to link in my custom module. This is the error I get:

```
libpython2.6.a(config.o):(.data+0xa8): undefined reference to `init_myplugin'
```

My plugin's name is '_myplugin'. I do not have a function in my C++ file that is names 'init_myplugin'. Help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: No, just basic C++ class and 'extern C' functions.

Comment: You should have an init function in your module. The name of your plugin is a bit strange, the underscore is probably unnecessary. The compiled shared object for module myplugin should be called _myplugin.so, on the other hand, but the name of the module: myplugin. Why would you not show us the code of your module, at least your init function?

Comment: I can't post any code on-line because it is proprietary to my company. My end goal is to just have my C++ file compiled into the libpython2.6.a library. It isn't actually a python module but I need it compiled into that library. I got this working on Windows without to many issues and now I need it for Linux.